# Printing not printing even though printer is found

Tags: 22.04, printing

I have a Samsung M2835DW series printer connected by an ethernet cable on my local LAN. I have been happily printing to it but it no longer prints at all.

When I go to http://localhost:631/printers/ I see the printer and in status it says

"Processing - "Connected to printer."

I tried killing the job and resubmitting it and turning the printer on and off, with no luck.

What can I do to diagnose and fix this problem?

Looking at var/log/cups/error_log I see:

```
W [26/Nov/2023:00:00:14 +0000] Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS. See https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups/issues/103
E [26/Nov/2023:00:00:17 +0000] [Client 18] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for CUPS-Create-Local-Printer (ipp://localhost/) from localhost.
E [26/Nov/2023:12:07:22 +0000] [Client 170] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for CUPS-Create-Local-Printer (ipp://localhost/) from localhost.
E [26/Nov/2023:12:07:27 +0000] [Client 175] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for CUPS-Create-Local-Printer (ipp://localhost/) from localhost.
E [26/Nov/2023:12:07:32 +0000] [Client 180] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for CUPS-Create-Local-Printer (ipp://localhost/) from localhost.
E [26/Nov/2023:12:07:37 +0000] [Client 185] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for CUPS-Create-Local-Printer (ipp://localhost/) from localhost.
E [26/Nov/2023:12:07:42 +0000] [Client 190] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for CUPS-Create-Local-Printer (ipp://localhost/) from localhost.
```

Comment: Can't remember why : "IF the printer can usb and lan print THEN try a print job via usb" will fix it and further network printings will go fine. Im keeping the usb printing port created but i print via network. Hope this will help.

Comment: Inspect the log files in `/var/log/cups/`

Comment: @waltinator I added the error log to the question.  Is there a way to "factory reset" a printer?